# Mysql 8 connect only with ssl-ca (server-ca.pem)

Tags: mysql, ssl, google-cloud-sql

I found an old [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/890358/connect-mysql-using-ssl-only-with-the-ssl-ca-option) in ServerFault on the same topic but I am not sure what has changed with MySQL 8. Do I need all 3, the server-ca, client-cert and client-key to make successful SSL connections to MySQL 8? I don't really care for client certificates (all my clients are exactly the same). So do I still need all 3? Also looking at Google Cloud MySQL and it lets me download just the server ca. Seems like the client certs are optional. However I can't seem to connect without the client certs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bit that's really important is the client key.

In my experience with GCP, depending on the exact setup, you can often just use the client key and client cert, rather than needing to supply the server certificate (which GCP stores on their end anyway).

Cloud SQL allows you to simply download the server CA because, fundamentally, it isn't as sensitive as the client cert/key. Those are private and only available once, when you first generate them. After that, if you didn't securely save them somewhere else, you cannot get them again (although you can revoke them if they ever get leaked).

The good news is that you can generate lots of client key/certificate pairs (whereas generating a new server certificate will likely schedule it to be rotated in at some point in the future), so there's no problem with your going ahead and generating some new ones.

Comment: Thank you. One follow up though. So it looks like there's no way to connect to Cloud SQL without the client certs. Is this possible with a standalong MySQL? As in just trusting the connection based on the SSL CA Cert without a client cert?

Comment: It is not required in general, if that's what you mean? You should be able to switch off SSL authentication in GCP Cloud SQL. Select your SQL instance, go to 'Connections' in the left hand menu, then choose the 'Security' tab and uncheck 'Allow only SSL connections'. In that case you will want to be 100% sure the data aren't sensitive and even so, you may wish to use an IP allow-list in the 'Networking' tab ('Authorized Networks' section).

Comment: I was asking about this "However, if SSL/TLS is not enforced, connecting with non-mutual TLS using the server certificate is still possible. " in ths link. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance It appears like without generating a client certificate, it is possible to just use the server-ca to allow non mutual TLS. But for this I believe I need to turn off "Allow only SSL connections" on the menu.

Comment: Do you just want to connect to the cloud SQL database and SSL is hampering you? Perhaps the [cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-instance-auth-proxy#install-proxy) - which opens a secure TLS tunnel to the Cloud SQL Instance and uses GCPs built-in identity and access management for authentication - would be suitable for your use case? If the proxy is running you can essentially 'pretend' the database is running on your machine and connect via localhost.

Comment: Thank you for persisting with me! I am using AWS' Schema Conversion Tool to onboard cloud SQL as the source. But the tool doesn't have an option to specify a keystore for the client cert. The tool does have an option to specify a trust store and I am able to add the server-ca as the trust store. However since the tool doesn't allow me to even use a client cert, I was wondering if it is possible to bypass the client cert and just authenticate SSL based on the server-ca.